# Is it correct to say "high level point of view"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage

The sentence: "We will look at it from a high level point of view (or perspective)."

Or is it better to just say: "We will look at it from a high level."

Or is there a better way to put it. I'm referring to a discussion on a specific topic that is soon to happen.

Comment: Most idiomatic is *high-level view.*

Comment: The expression "high level" is frequently used to refer to senior management. In this case the issue would be examined "at a high level" rather than "from a high level".

Comment: There is not enough detail here to permit a useful answer. Please use the [edit] link to add a description of the context in which you wish to use the expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two separate concepts you can say with "high-level" (or at least one of its synonyms).  One is to get an "overview", meaning to look at it from a broad perspective and not get into detail.  The other is to examine or talk about something *at* a high level, meaning to investigate or explain as if everyone already has a very good understanding of the subject, so you can focus on high-level concepts.

I don't know which of these you want to use.  If the first, then "We will get an overview (of the subject)" is the phrase you want.  If the second, then "look at this at a high level" gets your meaning across, although a better way might be, "We will discuss this at a high level" or "We will examine this at a high level".

Either way, "point of view" is unnecessary.